# SQL - Join multiple tables and count()

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to count the number of results in a column after joining a table and I am having a hard time getting my query to work.

In the end result, **I need to get a table with the product id, product name and the number of medias for each product**.

This is what I have so far:

SQL

```
select 
    p.id, 
    p.name, 
    count(distinct mp.media_id)
from products as p
left join medias_products as mp
    on mp.product_id = p.id
group by mp.media_id
order by p.id
```

These are the tables:

**Medias**

```
Id     | client id
------ | ---------
1      | 1
2      | 2
```

**Products**

```
id     | name     | client_id
------ | -------- | ---------
1      | product1 | 1
2      | product2 | 2
```

**medias_products**

```
product_id | media_id
---------- | --------
1          | 2
2          | 1
```

**Client**

```
id     | name
------ | -----
1      | Peter
2      | John
```

In addition, I'd like to find another query that would give me the results filtered by an specific client id.

Can someone please shed some light and share the knowledge.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is one basic issue which prevents your query from being accepted by the sql compiler: if you have a query with a group by-clause like "group by attrib1, attrib2", then the select-part must not contain any other attributes than attrib1 and attrib2 (except aggregate functions like count, sum, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    p.id, 
    min(p.name) as name, 
    count(distinct mp.media_id) as medias
from products as p
left join medias_products as mp
    on mp.product_id = p.id
group by p.id
order by p.id
```

For your second query:

```
select 
    p.id, 
    min(p.name) as name, 
    count(distinct mp.media_id) as medias
from products as p
inner join medias_products as mp
    on mp.product_id = p.id
inner join medias as m
    on m.id = mp.media_id
inner join clients as c
    on c.id = m.client_id
where c.id = <your client's id>
group by p.id
order by p.id
```

Comment: Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it, don't just dump a bunch of code.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you GROUP BY p.id instead of mp.media_id?  That is

```
select 
    p.id, 
    p.name, 
    count(distinct mp.media_id)
from 
    products as p
    left join medias_products as mp
        on p.id = mp.product_id
group by p.id
order by p.id
```